# BPMN Multiple User Inputs in Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, bpmn

I just started Researching on BPMN a few days ago, and I have a use case where the user needs to insert multiple inputs during the workflow, for example he first inserts a number and after using a service task to process that number I would like to provide the functionality for the user to change that number before invoking the service task again (All in one single workflow). Is this possible in BPMN or any other similar language? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think loops or sequential multi-instantiation and subprocesses are the BPMN features you're looking for.

First, create a subprocess task with the human task to enter the value followed by the service task.

Then, make the subprocess task as a loop which condition is based on when to stop it and continue the main process. If you know how many executions you want at the beginning of the loop, then a sequential multi-instantiation would do the job too.

Hope it helps